# Query on increase in size while exporting to pdf from ppt

Tags: pdf, powerpoint

I have a ppt for 100 EMF images which of size 884 KB. When I convert this ppt to pdf via export options in ppt I observe pdf file size increased to 4.58 MB. Any specific reason on why size increases so much and any way on how can we get pdf with reduced size while converting if from ppt?

Comment: There's never any guarantee that a PDF will be smaller than the file it was created from. As a test, create a copy of the file then copy/paste special/as JPG or PNG half a dozen or so of the EMFs. Save the file then make a PDF from it. Is it a bit smaller?  If so, that may be the answer.

Comment: EMFs are a non-PostScript vector format, but vectors in PDF are PostScript. Microsoft's conversion routine is inefficient, Office programs create really bad PostScript. If you can get a copy of Acrobat to create PDFs, they will be smaller and look better.

Comment: Late to the party here, but another possibility:  If you use a Mac, PowerPoint uses the MacOS' export to PDF feature rather than the one that's built into PPT/Word/Etc on the Windows side. Mac's PDF export is notorious for producing unreasonably huge PDF files

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, try to use [Aspose Online Converter](https://products.aspose.app/slides/conversion) for your presentations. This app is able to convert presentations to many formats and also works with EMF images. Perhaps your results will be better. I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.